# How to add platform specific subdir to qmake?

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a project which uses qmake, and at the top level I have a subdirs pro file. It looks something like this (simplified version):

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS  = Sample1 Sample2

win32 {
    SUBDIRS += WinProject
    message("Platform: Windows")
}
macx {
    SUBDIRS += MacProject
    message("Platform: MacOS")
}
unix:!macx {
    SUBDIRS += LinuxProject
    message("Platform: Linux")
}
```

So, what I want to do is to have some projects which will be included only for specific platforms. However, doing this includes all projects, regardless of the scope, although I am only getting "Platform: Windows" at the output.

Is there any way to add projects depending on the platform, or should I consider switching the whole project to cmake?

Comment: I would consider cmake if you are still early in the project development. In the newer version there are FIND_PACKAGES for QT and it's easy to set up moc'ing, etc, and build cross-platform QT projects.